# How to perform element-wise tests on a vector in Mata

Tags: stata

Suppose I have a vector `foo` defined in Mata thus:

```
mata: foo = (1,2,1,3,1,4)
```

How do I perform an element-wise test on `foo`? For example, in R, if I define foo thus:

```
foo = c(1,2,1,3,1,4)
```

I can simply type:

```
foo == 1
```

and I obtain as a result a vector of boolean values for the element-wise test `== 1`:

```
TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE
```

which I can then assign or perform operations on (e.g. count up the number of `TRUE` or `FALSE` values).

I could, of course take several lines of code to loop over each element, but wonder if the language has an elegant syntax for this task already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the colon (`:`) operator for element-by-element calculations.

```
mata

V = (1 \ 2 \ 3 \ 4)
V

V :== 1

end
```

See `help [M-2] op_colon` for details.

Comment: I am a moron: for some reason thought the element-wise operator was `*`, thanks for setting me straight.